# How do I refer to a javascript function on a php echo that echoes a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to echo this code on php but since there are many `''` it ends the html earlier than it should, how can I fix this.

```
function button($conn){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<button class='FASTFONT' onclick='openCity(event,'".$row['name']."')'>".$row['name']."</button>";

    }
}
```

**This is the output that I get:**

```
<button class="FASTFONT" onclick="openCity(event,"Blanda1')'>Blanda1</button>
```

Comment: Use `$name = $row['name']` and use `$name` in your `echo` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` statement needs to be changed, so that the quotations that match the opening and closing ones are properly escaped. Here's one way you can do this:

```
function button($conn){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
  $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<button class='FASTFONT' onclick='openCity(event,\"".$row['name']."\")'>".$row['name']."</button>";
  }
}
```

And the output should look something like this:

```
<button class='FASTFONT' onclick='openCity(event,"Blanda1")'>Blanda1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\"` instead of the regular `'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this :

```
function button($conn){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<button class="FASTFONT" onclick="openCity(event,\''.$row['name'].'\')">'.$row['name'].'</button>';

    }
}
```